# Error in displaying data after fetching it from the Sqlite DataBase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

throwing a fatal error while going to display message using TextView.. iam using this program
I sets some loger also.It is run good upto logger="lastmark".

```
        private void displayText(String message){
        logger.info("inside display message");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_1);
        logger.info("last mark");
        textView.setText(message);

    }
    public void callStatus(){

        logger.info("inside 3 rd step");
        dataBase = DataBaseManager.instance();

        logger.info("inside 4 rd step");
        //to get data from database we need a cursor.
        //after we perform a select query all the data from database specific for the query, will be in the cursor
        // "*" means "all" in translation the query means "SELECT ALL FROM NAME TABLE"

        cursor = dataBase.select("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
        logger.info("inside 4b rd step");
        String s ="";
        logger.info("inside 5 rd step");

        //the cursor iterates the column "name"
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            do{


            //in this string we get the record for each row from the column "name"
            logger.info("inside 6 rd step");
            String s1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME1));
            String s2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME2));
            s = s1+s2;
            }while  (cursor.moveToNext());
            logger.info("inside 7 rd step");
            //in this textView will be added, updated or deleted the string
            // "\n" means "new line"
        }

        //here we close the cursor because we do not longer need it
        cursor.close();
        logger.info("inside 8 rd step");
        displayText(s);
    }


}
```

....throwing a fatal error while going to display message using TextView.. iam using this program
    I sets some looger also.It is run good upto logger="lastmark".

Comment: This is probably because your textView is null when you call textView.setText(message); Where are you inflating your layout? Post your onCreate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

After creating the cursor

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
       // get column1 and column2 
       ....
    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
}
```

And make sure you close the cursor after all the cursor operations.

Answer (score 0):

I know ,before while (cursor.moveToNext()){……} ,you should  move the cursor to first
cursor.moveToFirst() must be performed firstly!